# Restarting search in a quick way

Tags: key-bindings, search

In Firefox I can hit `Ctrl-f` to start a search and `Ctrl-g` to search the next occurence of the string searched. If I would like to search for a different term, I simply hit `Ctrl-f` again and type in the new search term right away.

In emacs I hit `Ctrl-s` to search but if I don't find, what I was looking for (after multiple `Ctrl-s`) I have to hit `Ctrl-g` and then `Ctrl-s` again. Or I hit `backspace` multiple times to go back through the matches and finally delete character by character.

I thought about assigning `isearch-forward` to a different key to be able to restart the search dialog quickly.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: not sure if I'm following you, what you want is to clear words backwards to start the search again? like `M-DEL`? Also, movement bindings like `C-a C-k` should work in minibuffer too.

Comment: "*to be able to do this"* - to be able to do what? You can end Isearch and return to your starting point by repeating `C-g`. You can end it at any search hit with `RET`. You can edit the search pattern at any time using `M-e`. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: `M-DEL` for me only quits isearch. Same for `C-a`. I am looking for a single command to reset isearch like `Ctrl-f` in Firefox/Chrome. `M-e` is good to know, thanks. But it is not what I was looking for.